# Macro that autofills the cell based on drop down menu in excel

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

I need help for generating the macro that basically gives the value "200000" based on a drop down menu in a cell. This drop down menu has two defined values in it(120 and 480). If other value in the drop down menu is selected then, I should have the freedom of writing any value that I want. The code which I came up with is below

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$G$11")) Is Nothing Then
 Range("$B$20:$R$25,$Z$20:$AM$25").ClearContents
 End If

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$G$11")) Is Nothing Then
 Range("$F$16:$Q$16,$R$15:$U$16,$V$16:$AA$16,$AB$15:$AM$16").ClearContents
 End If

If Range("I16") = 120 Or Range("I16") = 480 Then
        Range("F16") = 200000
    Else
        Range("F16") = ""
    End If
exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Exit Sub


End Sub
```

However, I have another macro which clears all the contents in the cells due to which the above code is causing an error. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should show us the other macro then?  Not much we can do with the posted code.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for viewing. Please find below

Comment: ´´´´
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$G$11")) Is Nothing Then
 Range("$F$16:$Q$16,$R$15:$U$16,$V$16:$AA$16,$AB$15:$AM$16").ClearContents
 End If

Comment: Please *edit your question* if you need to add code - it's unreadable in comments.  Also, don't just post snippets - it's useful to know for example if you're using an event handler to fire your code (and I'd have to *guess* that, based on the presence of `Target` there...)   The less guessing we do the better.

Comment: Hi Tim, I am really sorry. I have edited the code as per your request in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're not re-triggering your event handler from within.
Also worth adding an error handler to make sure events aren't left turned off.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim v

    On Error GoTo exitHandler

    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("G11")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Me.Range("B20:R25,Z20:AM25,F16:Q16,R15:U16,V16:AA16,AB15:AM16").ClearContents
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("I16")) Is Nothing Then
        v = Target.Value
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Me.Range("F16").Value = IIf(v = 120 Or v = 480, 200000, "")
    End If

exitHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure where the problem is but will get back to you once I find the error. In this case, I would say that the Cell "F16" is merged but again, since I am no coder, the error is probably in the merged cell

Comment: If F16 is merged you need to address the top-left cell in that merged range in order to change its value.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. The macro that you have given is working.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just need to disable events before clearing cells so that the `Change` code is not triggered.

I'm not sure how the second bit of code relates so may need some adjustment.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$G$11")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("$B$20:$R$25,$Z$20:$AM$25").ClearContents
        Range("$F$16:$Q$16,$R$15:$U$16,$V$16:$AA$16,$AB$15:$AM$16").ClearContents
        If Range("I16") = 120 Or Range("I16") = 480 Then 'presumably belongs elswhere as just cleared I16 above?
            Range("F16") = 200000
        Else
            Range("F16").Clear
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
exitHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub

End Sub
```